# How to create screenshot of QWidget?

Tags: qt, save, qwidget, qpixmap

I work at my homework in Qt Creator, where I paint to QWidget and I need to save some part of this QWdiget.

I tried to solve this problem:

```
 QPixmap pixmap;
 pixmap.copy(rectangle); // rectangle is part of QWidget, which I need to save
 pixmap.save("example.png");
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`QWidget::render`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#render) for this. Assuming `rectangle` is a QRect:

```
QPixmap pixmap(rectangle->size()); 
widget->render(&pixmap, QPoint(), QRegion(rectangle));
```

Comment: how do you save it to a file?

Comment: @bachurim09: the code in the question does that. Please also check the docs for QPixmap.

Comment: In a nutshell, that's:
`pixmap.save("Hello.jpg");`

The docs are located at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpixmap.html.

Answer (score 8):

From [QWidget::Grab](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab):

```
QPixmap QWidget::grab(const QRect &rectangle = QRect(QPoint(0, 0), QSize(-1, -1)))
```

Comment: Genius !  I'm making my widgets drag-n-dropable.  And the mime data has an icon that you can set, which shows up under the cursor when you drag outside of the container.